# a non well formed numeric value encountered codeigniter php 7.*

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7

I have upgraded my project from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.*

I encountered a non well formed numeric value encountered.

```
$AmountDue      = number_format($this->input->post('AmountDue'), 2, '.','');
$AmountPaid     = number_format($this->input->post('AmountPaid'), 2, '.','');
```

I tried to var_dump() the value of those functions

here's the result.

```
string(4) "1.16" 
string(7) "1479.75"
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate as this question doesn't specifically ask about `number_format()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably `$this->input->post('AmountDue')` causing the problem. The function `number_format` expects a float datatype as the first argument. PHP 7+ is much more finicky about datatypes that previous versions.

I think you can get rid of the error by typecasting the post values e.g.

```
$AmountDue = number_format( (float) $this->input->post('AmountDue'), 2, '.','');
```